# AJAX sends the variable properly, but unable to retrieve it in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post, get

I'm passing a variable (winner_id) through AJAX to ajax.php. It seems that ajax works fine and it passes the variable, however my ajax.php doesn't seem to get it. I'm unable to assign it to a php variable for further use.

Here is my code:

## **JavaScript (AJAX)**

```
function ajaxCall(winner_id) {

        $.ajax
        ({
                url: "ajax.php?winner_id=" + winner_id,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(response)
                  { 
                     alert("The winner was passed!");
                  }
        });
};
ajaxCall(winner_id);
```

## **PHP** *(ajax.php)*

```
<?php 
session_start();

$winner_id = $_GET['winner_id'];
echo json_encode(array("winner_id" => $winner_id));

exit;

?>
```

Now, for example I'm passing **winner_id = 3** in AJAX. When I open it my **Developer Tools/ Network/ click on ajax.php/ Preview** this is what I see:

**winner_id: "3"** -> which is correct!

However, if I call ajax.php directly in my browser I see this:

```
{
    winner_id: null
}
```

If I **var_dump($_GET, $_POST)** I get: **array(0) { } array(0) { }**.

I am 100% positive that my ajax call is working correctly, however I have no idea why I can't get the values in php. I've seen similar questions here on stackoverflow but was unable to find an answer.

I'm using .htaccess for error forwarding, and maybe that could be an issue because for other people this code worked just fine. I really need help! Thank you!

Comment: please put your form tags here

Comment: No, I'm running it on my local host @vcardillo

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new in webdev, which form are you talking about? Thanks! @SamithaHewawasam

Comment: $_GET['winner_id'];  where this coming from

Comment: _However, if I call ajax.php directly in my browser..._, well if you call `ajax.php` of course it will be null what if you call `ajax.php?winner_id=3`

Comment: "However, if I call ajax.php directly in my browser" -- You are requesting ajax.php?winner_id=3 right? Not just ajax.php

Comment: Thank you! That makes total sense! @vcardillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, for example I'm passing winner_id = 3 in AJAX. When I open it my
>   Developer Tools/ Network/ click on ajax.php/ Preview this is what I
>   see:

```
winner_id: "3" -> which is correct!
```

And if you check the Response in Developer tools, you should also see:

```
{
    winner_id: 3
}
```

If you call `ajax.php` in your browser, then yes, winner_id would be null. However if you call `ajax.php?winner_id=3` then you should see your same JSON response as noted above.